# Why MySQL GTID not support temporary tables

Tags: mysql, gtid

I read from MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-gtids-restrictions.html)

> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE and DROP TEMPORARY TABLE statements are not supported inside transactions when using GTIDs (that is, when the server was started with the --enforce-gtid-consistency option). It is possible to use these statements with GTIDs enabled, but only outside of any transaction, and only with autocommit=1

and very confused why CREATE/DROP TEMPORARY TABLE not supported inside transactions when GTID is enable, can someone explain in more detail? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are reasons most likely relating to replication when GTID is enabled.  You can always create a normal table inside a transaction.  `Drop` that table `if exists` before creating.  It will work the same way as temporary table.